# Running C++ code through NUnit

Tags: c#, c++, nunit, appdomain

I have tried to use NUnit to test C# code the is already connected to C++ code (without the NUnit the application work perfectly).

In my test I run the main function through AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly(..), However when the C# code tries to "communicate" with the C++ it throws an exception and the test crashes. The exception is System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException if anyone has and idea why its happen it will be very very helpful... Thanks, Naama

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to isolate the bit of code throwing that exception?  Is the exception being thrown in the C# or C++ application?

Comment: Did you have to add anything to your app.config in your app?

Comment: I have used the debugger, and I isolated the code where the exception is being through.
It is happen when I am trying to create an object in c++ that is contained in a c# object.
And i havnt add anyhing to the app.config in my application

Comment: NAAMA, Please paste the relevent code in your question.  I suspect an exception is being thrown in your constructor.

Comment: Is there an inner exception in the TargetInvocationException giving more details?

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicions are correct it is being through during the constructor, the constructor in c# is trying to create an object (it is already wrapped and work perfect when the application is running normally) that is written in c++ and in c++ in the constructor of the object the exception is thrown.
However the application is very complex but if it necessary for clarification I will write a demo application that symbol the real one.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that an exception is being thrown in your C++ code, in the constructor of the class.  Check to make sure you're handling exceptions properly and that you're giving the proper information to the constructor so exceptions aren't thrown.